# 2 domain name (EN/FR) 1 FTP redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, ftp

I've a problem with my .htaccess file.

I have two domaine name associate to the same FTP server.
One domaine name is in English and the other one is in French.

For now,

1. if users type english-hostname.com -> it links to index.html
   (classic)
2. if users type french-hostname.com -> it also links to
       the same index.html

So here is what I would like to have :

1. if users type english-hostname.com -> it links to index.html
2. if users type french-hostname.com -> it should links to
   index-fr.html

As I don't really want the "index-fr.html" appears into the url, I created a subfolder called "fr" and I placed the french index in it.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^french-hostname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.french-hostanme.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^english-hostanme.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.english-hostname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am clearly not familiar with these redirection/rewriting rules, every time I try something this code break my website (error 500...)

Any idea please?

Thank you !

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place each version in a dedicated folder for a better organisation. Then, you need additional conditions to redirect your domains correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?english-hostname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?french-hostname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1
```

Keep in mind that *http://english-hostname.com/fr/* is still accessible and conversely.